Burger equation and shock waves
Given the burger equation, $$m_{\tau} + mm_x = 0,$$ one expects to have discontinuities and thus shock waves in the case the initial conditions are smooth. For example, one may take $$m_0(x) = \sin(x), x\in[0,\pi]$$ as initial conditions. Then, the characteristic lines would be $$x = x_0 + \sin(x_0)\tau$$ which will cross and thus we expect shock waves. Assuming we have a shallow water environment, or let's say a home made experiment, why we do not observe the shock wave if we generate a sine wave on the water surface?

Real water has viscocity

I voted to move this to Physics StackExchange, but your question is basically "This equation exhibits X, why doesn't the real world exhibit X?" and the answer is because very few real scenarios can be modeled by an inviscid Burgers equation in 1D
